# expect_out(buffer) not capturing all the data while being called via php

Tags: php, tcl, expect

I am trying to get configuration details from a switch via expect script. 
I have below piece working fine as expected when i call via shell manually.
But when the same called via, php ( to build a web interface to call this) somehow expect_out(buffer) doesn't have all the lines filled and my match fails.
I am trying to match configuration bit set or not.
Again code works when called manually, just that via php this somehow fails to fill expect_out(buffer) :( :(

Working code.

```
#!/usr/bin/expect
set ip ROUTER_IP
set uname USER_NAME
set psd PASSWORD
set log_file -a "/tmp/script.log"
spawn /usr/bin/ssh $uname@$ip
expect {
    "ord:" {
        send "$psd\r"
        expect {
            "> " {
                send "\r"
                set cmd "show configuration | display set | match class | match rancid"
                set values $expect_out(buffer)
                send_log "\nbefore trim n match -$values-\n"
                set values [string trim $values]
                send_log "\nbefore match -$values-\n"
                set found [regexp {match rancid\s+(.*)\s+\r\n\{.*} $values match px]
                if { $found == 1  && $px != "" } {
                    puts "Rancid Exists... !!!"
                    send "exit\r"
                    exit 1
                } else { 
                    puts "Coundnt find Rancid ... !!!"
                    send "exit\r"
                    exit 2
                }
            }
            "denied: " {
                puts "ERROR: Access Denied"
                exit 2
            }
        }
    }
}
```

I am calling this via php like this,

```
$res=shell_exec("/usr/bin/expect $scriptPath ");
```

I could see, expect_out(buffer) which is set to $values, is being filled with half commands output from log_file.
Succesfull expect_out(buffer),

```
before trim match -show configuration | display set | match class | match rancid ^M
set system login user rancid class remote-backup^M
^M
{master:1}^M
USER_NAME@SWITCH> -

before match -show configuration | display set | match class | match rancid ^M
set system login user rancid class remote-backup^M
^M
{master:1}^M
USER_NAME@SWITCH>-
```

when called via php, expect_out(buffer) looks like this,

```
before trim match -show configuration | display set | m^MUSER_NAME@SWITCH> -

before match -show configuration | display set | m^MUSER_NAME@SWITCH>-
```

Somehow, when expect script called via php, buffer doesn't have all the commands output and match fails. 
 Can someone guide me what could be the mistake.Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

Why do the things differ? Well, there's all sorts of possible reasons. Different timing can be one of them; that's *very* possible and very difficult to prevent. You simply have to write your code to adapt to the variation; fortunately that's fairly easy.

In general, using `$expect_out(buffer)` itself is not recommended as it is *not* defined just how much data is accumulated in it. It'll probably have as much as it needed to match the `expect`ed pattern, but really isn't guaranteed to match much more than that. I'd expect the script to be more like this:

```
#!/usr/bin/expect
set ip ROUTER_IP
set uname USER_NAME
set psd PASSWORD
set log_file -a "/tmp/script.log"
spawn /usr/bin/ssh $uname@$ip

# Less nesting here! Makes the code much simpler to read
expect "ord:"
send "$psd\r"
expect {
    "> " {
        send_log "logged in\n"
    }
    "denied: " {
        puts "ERROR: Access Denied"
        exit 2
    }
}

# Classic code to read a multi-line result from a remote site, ONE LINE AT A TIME
set cmd "show configuration | display set | match class | match rancid"
send "$cmd\r"; # Had you forgotten this in pasting?
set values ""
expect {
    -re {^(.*\S|)\r?\n} {
        append values $expect_out(1,string) "\n"
        exp_continue
    }
    "> " {
        # Got the prompt again
    }
}

# This is your code again
send_log "\nbefore trim n match -$values-\n"
set values [string trim $values]
send_log "\nbefore match -$values-\n"
set found [regexp {match rancid\s+(.*)\s+\r\n\{.*} $values match px]
if { $found == 1  && $px != "" } {
    puts "Rancid Exists... !!!"
    send "exit\r"
    exit 1
} else { 
    puts "Coundnt find Rancid ... !!!"
    send "exit\r"
    exit 2
}
```

In general, you should try to structure your code so that you are interleaving your `expect`s and `send`s, though a sequence of several `expect`s in a row can be OK. However, you can think of it as if the `send` isn't really processed until the next `expect`.

Note the use of `exp_continue`. That's a very powerful feature of Expect, which lets you keep the current `expect` statement doing more matching. It lets you build matcher loops, such as the one I did, and greatly simplifies many interaction problems. And for goodness' sake, try to avoid nesting the code as much as you can! Programs are hard enough without making them extra complicated!

Comment: It's a deep truth of computing that simple programs that work on your own machine on a good day can fail as soon as the environment changes (and web servers are a different environment). Writing the code to adapt takes more work — though not much more in this case — and means that it won't suddenly break when you don't expect it.

Comment: Thanks for the code snippet @donal. yes these environments are tricky to handle. Can you please help me understand that separate expect block with {.*\n} and exp_continue part?     Something to be changed on the match regex looks like, its not working now, logs - https://filebin.net/3wr14jj21rbk70n5

Comment: **The log helps a lot!** Looking at it, are you actually looking for the text `{master:1}`? It's _much_ easier to make expect work if you are looking for something specific. (We need to move the pattern to extract the real data above the pattern to match the prompt; order of matching matters.) The core problem is that due to _timing differences_ (out of our control) we're getting multiple lines at once in the match buffer.

Comment: I am trying to match string before {master:1} , basically string before {. So in case if user class is already created, then show commad would output something, if not it would reply empty, hence i was trying to put / match things before that {, and store it in px variable. I have also tried below regex, but none seem to work :( <br>`set found [regexp { .*$cmd\s+\r\n(.*login user rancid class remote-backup)\s+\r\n\{.*} $value match px ]`<br>
`set found [regexp { .*rancid\s+\r\n\{.*} $value match px ]`

Comment: OK, I'm not quite sure how to decide whether you've found anything as I don't know the format that is being matched against there… but I'm pretty sure how to extract the data you care about. Assuming you don't have spaces at the end of lines you care about. The rest of your problem is then just about deciding when a string is matched, and not how to persuade the router to tell you the info.

Comment: Let me try this part.